# How to add a new setting to dconf-editor?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to save touchpad settings, so I need to add the path to touchpad_settings.sh to hotplug-command. It should be in org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices but there is no input-devices in the peripherals folder. I need to set up two-finger horizontal scrolling.

[image: screenshot].

I didn't put the dconf tag because I don't have enough reputation to create it.

Answer (score 2):

All GSettings-based GNOME programs (with very rare exceptions) pre-declare all supported settings in "schema" files that they install. If dconf-editor isn't showing a particular setting, it's because setting isn't in the program's GSettings schema, and that usually means the program **will not care about that setting even if you add it.**

In particular, the "hotplug-command" setting was [removed in GNOME 3.20](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/commit/c50ceb880e928506d987747f9e554079ad3d9826). As you can see from the commit, it wasn't just taken out of the schema, but the actual code that would run the command got removed as well.

You can use the `dconf write` command to add settings that don't correspond to any schema, but this will achieve nothing useful when there's no program code that would read that setting.

So instead of doing this, you should configure the settings through GNOME itself – everything that's configurable can be found at `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` in dconf-editor (as well as in the GNOME Tweaks app).

Comment: I need to set up two-finger horizontal scrolling. It turns out that since this parameter is not there, then it can not be configured in any way?

Comment: As far as I know it's enabled by default, and the same `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled` parameter controls both vertical _and_ horizontal scrolling. Are you using libinput or xf86-input-synaptics? (Keep in mind that although you can still control other parameters directly via `xinput` or `synclient` while in X11, that will no longer work in Wayland.)